# My libgdx game runs un desktop but not in android

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, game-development

You see, I've been programming a long-time game with Libgdx, I always used gradlew to install an apk debug and try it on my android, the thing is that I have it finished, it weighs a lot, and I test it with gradlew on my cellphone, but the difference is that now it doesn't run, it doesn't run on android but it does in the desktop. Why? I don't know what is wrong, I didn't put code because it is a lot and as I said nothing is wrong, just do not run on Android. -I use eclipse.
The worst part is that I don't know what I did, because before it ran me on android.

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication>
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>

<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
                 android:targetPackage="com.cubopez.es"
                 android:handleProfiling="false"
                 android:functionalTest="false"
                 android:label="Tests for com.cubopez.es"/>


</manifest>
```

(This didn't work before I tried to add the Multidex)

Error message (I tried to delete the mp3 asset that provocated that error, but it failed again with other mp3 asset):

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 22480Process:
>   com.cubopez.blast, PID: 31220Theme:
>   themes:{default=overlay:com.zui.theme.XuiSkin.blue, iconPack:system,
>   fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system,
>   com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException:
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies
>   of asset: winter.mp3 at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError(AssetManager.java:582)
>   at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:383)
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.finishLoading(AssetManager.java:404)
>   at com.cubopez.blast.MainGame.create(MainGame.java:129) at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:311)
>   at
>   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1519)
>   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
>
> Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load
>   dependencies of asset: winter.mp3 at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:121)
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:90)
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:507)
>   at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:381)
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.finishLoading(AssetManager.java:404) 
>   at com.cubopez.blast.MainGame.create(MainGame.java:129)  at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:311) 
>   at
>   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1519) 
>   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
>
> Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException:
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading audio file:
>   winter.mp3Note: Internal audio files must be placed in the assets
>   directory. at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncResult.get(AsyncResult.java:46) at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:119)
>   ... 8 more
>
> Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException:
>   Error loading audio file: winter.mp3Note: Internal audio files must be
>   placed in the assets directory. at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidAudio.newMusic(AndroidAudio.java:120)
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.MusicLoader.loadAsync(MusicLoader.java:48)
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.MusicLoader.loadAsync(MusicLoader.java:29)
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:70)
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34)
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:58)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>
> Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: winter.mp3 at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method) at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:357) at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.getAssetFileDescriptor(AndroidFileHandle.java:237)
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidAudio.newMusic(AndroidAudio.java:110)
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.MusicLoader.loadAsync(MusicLoader.java:48) 
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.MusicLoader.loadAsync(MusicLoader.java:29) 
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:70) 
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34) 
>   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:58) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Part of the code that charges the assets:

```
  public class MainGame extends Game {
private AssetManager manager;
private BaseScreen menu, levels, game;
protected int Height, Width;
private boolean isLoaded = false;
    private Texture pez;
    @Override
    public void create () {

manager = new AssetManager();
manager.load("cubopez.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("menu.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("levels.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("playButton.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("background1.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("background2.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("background3.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("winscreen.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("cubopezgrade1.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("cubopezgrade2.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("cubopezgrade3.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("cubopezgrade4.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("cubopezgrade5.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("cubopezgrade6.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("cubopezgrade7.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("supercubopez.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("supercubopez1.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("supercubopez2.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("supercubopez3.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("supercubopez4.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("supercubopez5.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("supercubopez6.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("supercubopez7.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("supercubopez8.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("rubik8bits.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("alga1.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("alga2.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("alga3.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("alga4.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("mar.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("cementerio.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("nieve.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("martick.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("cementeriotick.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("nievetick.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("mistery.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavidavacia.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida1.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida2.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida3.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida4.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida5.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida6.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida7.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida8.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida9.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida10.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavidavaciaboss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida1boss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida2boss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida3boss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida4boss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida5boss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida6boss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida7boss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida8boss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida9boss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("barradavida10boss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("rubik8bitsscrambled.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("cubopezmuerto.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("neodimio.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("skeltoncubopez.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("gameover.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("ghostfish.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("titulo.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("tiburon.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("tiburon2.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("nado.ogg", Sound.class);
manager.load("punch.ogg", Sound.class);
manager.load("boss.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("copo.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("copo2.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("copo3.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("estalactita.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("bubble.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("bubble2.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("bubble3.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("bossbackground.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("darkcubopez.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("mirror.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("powerup.ogg", Sound.class);
manager.load("music1.ogg", Music.class);
manager.load("fight.ogg", Music.class);
manager.load("winter.ogg", Music.class);
manager.load("music2.ogg", Music.class);
manager.load("winsound.ogg", Music.class);
manager.load("gameoversound.ogg", Sound.class);
manager.load("pyraminx.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("info.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("pyraminxscrambled.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("mirrorcube.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("mirrorscrambled.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("megaminx.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("megaminxscrambled.png", Texture.class);
manager.load("menusound.ogg", Music.class);








     manager.finishLoading();
```

Comment: what does it mean _it doesn't run_ - any errors?

Comment: @Enigo It crashed when it opens, there is no crash report because is my cellphone and it hasn't console to display, but when I open my app, the screen turns black and then without saying noting, it stops and it sends me to the menu of my phone, I don't know why. Please help me I've been a lot of time making this proyect and I want to release it :'(, but the fact that doesn't run on android doesn't help. Let me see the manifest and I will post it, but as I say, before it ran, and I didn't modificate those folders.

Comment: Okay, the one thing I can suggest you is, please, try to run it plugged to your PC, so you have some output in the console. As it's described here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-setup,-running-&-debugging. Because without an error message there's not much I can help you with.

Comment: Ok, I will try to get the error message and post it here, so please when I do that help me, because I feel frustrated that  I can't launch it. :(

Comment: Ok, I've got the message error, it seems like so many files can't load in the assetmanager like the songs, i dont know why in android not but in desktop works, please help me, what should I do? Above, in the question I edited it and I added the error message. ;)

Comment: well, it's pretty clear from the stacktrace that you don't have proper assets structure:
_Error loading audio file: winter.mp3Note: Internal audio files must be placed in the assets directory_       
[this page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling) should help you

Comment: @Enigo But I have every asset in the assets folder, besides, there are only two songs that can't load, the others mp3 assets don't throw any errors, and all my assets are saved  the same in that folder.

Comment: @Enigo Trying to solve it, I converted al the mp3 audios to ogg and it ran, but I don't know why it fixed, and I'm scared about releasing it because I don't know if it just fixed it in my phone. Do you know what happened? :(

Comment: hm, it shouldn't matter for this particular exception what format you have, unless you load it somehow not correctly. have you tried to put the mp3 files in *exactly the same* place as ogg files? if yes, then post the piece of code where you load the music

Comment: Yes, I just changed to ogg, anything more, I just replaced the mp3 assets by the oggs assets,but I will edit the post and put the piece of code that loads it.

Comment: Ok, I just put the code in my post, the "wintersound" and the "winsound" were the only songs that threw the exceptions, and are saved in the asset folder just like the other songs, but when I changed to ogg, it fixed.

Comment: Hey, I just saw another weird thing, I installed in my phone the app, and it ran, but without changing the assetmanager I instaled it again but now it crashes and the crash report says the same thing but whit other audio, "menusound", and before that audio didn't provocate exceptions :(

Comment: Hm, that piece of code looks alright. To help you I need to see the whole protect, probably. Try some things. Seems that the real issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @Enigo I put try catch blocks to avoid the crash, the try contains the load and the catch an algorithm that unable that audio in the whole game, but, like that some audios doesn't play, and the screen shows me other exception (it doesn't close), can you see please? I made other post with this error, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/q/51489427/9328658

Answer (score -1):

It may be about your texture atlas resolution... If the resolution is big and the phone you test on is an outdated one. Some devices can't handle more than 1024x1024

Comment: And if it  is the problem. What should I do? I don't know what is the texture atlas resolution, I'm new in this. Besides, did I change it? Because, before it ran  on  my android, but one day that I installed the app to test my advances again (as always), it started to crash.

Comment: Atlas resolution is the resolution of the images you use in the game... Did you combined them to make an atlas or do you use separate images?

Comment: I just save images in the asset folder of android, and then I load them separate by the assetmanager, as always, and it always worked for me, but one day, it stoped working in android.

Comment: So, you didn't add any images to the game in between the time it was working and it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, I always added images in that time, but the same way that I always did, what could I have done wrong? And what should I do to solve it?

Comment: No, the error was a failed load of a mp3 asset. Could you see te error message above (I eddited the post) and please help me? (If you realized, sorry by my bad english, but I write here because nobody answers me in the server of my language) :(