# Some audios of my libgdx game doesn't load in android but it does en desktop

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have every audio in my asset folder, they are .ogg and I load them by the asset manager, but sometimes that I install the apk on my android, it throws me an error message:

E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
I/QComExtractorFactory: Sniff: Set key to use qti parser
I/ExtendedExtractor: ExtendedExtractor::create 0x0

And when I quit some auidios it fixes, but then when I install the apk again, it shows me another exception with another auidio that before loaded correctly, but now fails by this error. Why?
I tried to solve it converting mp3 files into ogg files, and it fixed the load for a while... but when I reinstalled the apk with android studio throw me more exceptions with other audio files that before loaded correctly, AGAIN. And it just happens with audio files, my png images in the same folder load well. (I have every audio saved in the assets folders the same, and sometimes one don't load and sometimes it's other).

Part of my code that charges the audio:

```
    public class MainGame extends Game { private AssetManager manager; private BaseScreen menu, levels, game; protected int Height, Width; private boolean isLoaded = false; private Texture pez; @Override public void create () { manager = new AssetManager(); manager.load("cubopez.png", Texture.class); manager.load("menu.png", Texture.class); manager.load("levels.png", Texture.class); manager.load("playButton.png", Texture.class); manager.load("background1.png", Texture.class); manager.load("background2.png", Texture.class); manager.load("background3.png", Texture.class); manager.load("winscreen.png", Texture.class); manager.load("cubopezgrade1.png", Texture.class); manager.load("cubopezgrade2.png", Texture.class); manager.load("cubopezgrade3.png", Texture.class); manager.load("cubopezgrade4.png", Texture.class); manager.load("cubopezgrade5.png", Texture.class); manager.load("cubopezgrade6.png", Texture.class); manager.load("cubopezgrade7.png", Texture.class); manager.load("supercubopez.png", Texture.class); manager.load("supercubopez1.png", Texture.class); manager.load("supercubopez2.png", Texture.class); manager.load("supercubopez3.png", Texture.class); manager.load("supercubopez4.png", Texture.class); manager.load("supercubopez5.png", Texture.class); manager.load("supercubopez6.png", Texture.class); manager.load("supercubopez7.png", Texture.class); manager.load("supercubopez8.png", Texture.class); manager.load("rubik8bits.png", Texture.class); manager.load("alga1.png", Texture.class); manager.load("alga2.png", Texture.class); manager.load("alga3.png", Texture.class); manager.load("alga4.png", Texture.class); manager.load("mar.png", Texture.class); manager.load("cementerio.png", Texture.class); manager.load("nieve.png", Texture.class); manager.load("martick.png", Texture.class); manager.load("cementeriotick.png", Texture.class); manager.load("nievetick.png", Texture.class); manager.load("mistery.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavidavacia.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida1.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida2.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida3.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida4.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida5.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida6.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida7.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida8.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida9.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida10.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavidavaciaboss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida1boss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida2boss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida3boss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida4boss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida5boss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida6boss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida7boss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida8boss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida9boss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("barradavida10boss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("rubik8bitsscrambled.png", Texture.class); manager.load("cubopezmuerto.png", Texture.class); manager.load("neodimio.png", Texture.class); manager.load("skeltoncubopez.png", Texture.class); manager.load("gameover.png", Texture.class); manager.load("ghostfish.png", Texture.class); manager.load("titulo.png", Texture.class); manager.load("tiburon.png", Texture.class); manager.load("tiburon2.png", Texture.class); manager.load("nado.ogg", Sound.class); manager.load("punch.ogg", Sound.class); manager.load("boss.png", Texture.class); manager.load("copo.png", Texture.class); manager.load("copo2.png", Texture.class); manager.load("copo3.png", Texture.class); manager.load("estalactita.png", Texture.class); manager.load("bubble.png", Texture.class); manager.load("bubble2.png", Texture.class); manager.load("bubble3.png", Texture.class); manager.load("bossbackground.png", Texture.class); manager.load("darkcubopez.png", Texture.class); manager.load("mirror.png", Texture.class); manager.load("powerup.ogg", Sound.class); manager.load("music1.ogg", Music.class); manager.load("fight.ogg", Music.class); manager.load("winter.ogg", Music.class); manager.load("music2.ogg", Music.class); manager.load("winsound.ogg", Music.class); manager.load("gameoversound.ogg", Sound.class); manager.load("pyraminx.png", Texture.class); manager.load("info.png", Texture.class); manager.load("pyraminxscrambled.png", Texture.class); manager.load("mirrorcube.png", Texture.class); manager.load("mirrorscrambled.png", Texture.class); manager.load("megaminx.png", Texture.class); manager.load("megaminxscrambled.png", Texture.class); manager.load("menusound.ogg", Music.class); manager.finishLoading();
```

Comment: Please, could you share the part of your code where you load the audios? I'll try to do the same to see if I can replicate your error

Comment: Ok, I posted it :)

Comment: @LuisFernandoFrontanilla It is supossed that there is nothing wrong, because It runs me in desktop, in android is the fail.